# Could I get some help troubleshooting my if else statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code but to no avail. The second column keeps coming up as undefined so I definitely know it is an issue with my if else statements in javascript. If you could help me out that would be great!

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
var grades = ["70", "69", "100", "95", "60"];{
var passed ;
if (grades > 69) {
    passed = "Passed";
} else if (grades <70) {
    passed = "Failed";
}
}
document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Grades</th><th>Passed / Failed</th></tr>'); 

for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + grades[i] + '</td><td>' + passed + '</td></tr>');
    }

document.write('</table>')
```

Comment: That's not the issue. 60 is indeed < 70, so it should work. However, `if ( grades > 69 )` is meaningless when `grades` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should not write code like what you are doing now...

try this :

```js
var grades = ["70", "69", "100", "95", "60"];

function isPassed(point){
 var passed ;
if (point >= 70) {
    passed = "Passed";
} else if (point <70) {
    passed = "Failed";
}
return passed
}

document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Grades</th><th>Passed / Failed</th></tr>'); 

for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + grades[i] + '</td><td>' +  isPassed(grades[i]) + '</td></tr>');
    }

document.write('</table>')
```

Answer (score 0):

`grades` is an array, so `if (grades > 69)` and `if (grades <70)` are meaningless.

It sounds like you need to check each grade as you are displaying the table:

```
for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
  {
     if ( grades[i] > 69 ) {
       passed = 'Passed'
     } else if ( grades[i] < 70 ) {
       passed = 'Failed'
     }

     document.write('<tr><td>' + grades[i] + '</td><td>' + passed + '</td></tr>');  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate pass/fail for each mark. you can loop through the logic for each mark using a function and populate the result

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
var grades = ["70", "69", "100", "95", "60"];

  function getpassed(grades){
    var passed;
if (grades > 69) {
    passed = "Passed";
} else if (grades <70) {
    passed = "Failed";
}
    return passed;
}

document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Grades</th><th>Passed / Failed</th></tr>'); 

for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        document.write('<tr><td>' + grades[i] + '</td><td>' + getpassed(grades[i]) + '</td></tr>');
    }

document.write('</table>')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to iterate the `grades` array. Put the if else inside the `for` loop and check for `grades[i]` instead of the entire `grades` array.

```js
<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
var grades = ["70", "69", "100", "95", "60"];
var passed;


document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th>Grades</th><th>Passed / Failed</th></tr>');

for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  if (grades[i] > 69) {
    passed = "Passed";
  } else if (grades[i] < 70) {
    passed = "Failed";
  }
  document.write('<tr><td>' + grades[i] + '</td><td>' + passed + '</td></tr>');
}

document.write('</table>')
```